# Egypt at the time of Cleopatra

Tags: roman-empire, ancient-egypt

Edited question:

At the time of Cleopatra, were common rites and practises like for example the mummification of emperors, polytheism, the Pharaoh having the position of a living god present like they used to be in ancient Egypt, or is the typical picture of how for example documentaries often depict everyday life in ancient Egypt mostly attributed to a time much longer ago, say, for example, when the Pyramids of Giza were constructed?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far?

Comment: I think you need to edit this. Think about what purpose the first paragraph serves - do you need it? Better to show what key similarities and differences you have noted so far in your research and then frame your question around that.

Comment: Apart from the fact that they both lived in Egypt, Cleopatra and the ancient pharaohs came from entirely different backgrounds at very different times. So why would  you think they would be the same? You need to explain that in your question.

Comment: This question would benefit from preliminary research.

Answer (score 6):

The Kingdom of Egypt in Cleopatra's time was not like Ancient Egypt. It was then the [Kingdom of Ptolemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemaic_Kingdom) - one of a various Hellenistic kingdoms created when when Alexander the Great died.

It had a blend of Greek and ancient Egyptian cultures. The dominant elites were Greek.

Comment: But didn't Ptolemaic dynasty adopt a good deal of earlier Egyptian culture? I understand even Romans in Egypt practised forms of mummification, for example.

Comment: @TheHonRose: Totally. Per the article I linked to, it embraced its gods and religious practices (after modifying them somewhat), etc. Per my answer it was a blend.

Comment: Ok thank you, that sounds like there were still some former traits present during that time. And I guess as Greece and Rome had similar kinds of temples and for example houses, the overall architecture, you know, big buildings with hieroglyphs and paintings on the wall would have looked similar in that time like the ones two thousand years before.